# Filter Array inside for each not getting results

Tags: sharepoint-online, retention

So obviously I am lacking all skills to build or even search for the solution to my issue.
I hope there's someone here who can help me.

I need to remove the retention label on a couple of files in a SharePoint folder.
The files are nested inside subfolders.
I have found a script that loops through the folders and resets the label. However, the 5.000 items list view threshold of SharePoint Online prevents me from running the script smoothly.

So I came up with a solution.

First I am caching all list items into an array.

```
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List Documents -PageSize 500
```

This is how an item inside this array looks like:
[image]

So now I have this.

Next, I am looping through all folders I receive only the GUID from a file (from SharePoint). Not the ID.
So while I am looping through the I want to lookup the item in the array by using the GUID.
I thought of using a filter action inside the foreach.
Eventually, I need to have the ID value (number) of the file so I can perform a Set-PnPListItem action.

I am getting stuck at the filter action inside the foreach. I simply can't get it to work after struggling and searching for 2.5 hours.

This is what I have now:

```
       $itemsColl=Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $newFolderURL -ItemType File

       foreach($ArrayItem in $itemsColl){
       $GUID = $ArrayItem.UniqueId.Guid
       $resultaat = $ListItems | Where {$_["FieldValues"]["GUID"] -eq $ArrayItem.UniqueId.Guid} # DOESN'T WORK
       $resultaat = $ListItems | Where-Object $a = @($_.FieldValues.GUID) {$ListItems | Where-Object $a -eq $ArrayItem.FieldValues.Guid} # DOESN'T WORK
       Write-Host $resultaat.FieldValues.ID
       }
```

Unfortunately I can't get it to work. I doubt if it is because of the nested FieldValues, or that my nested $_ references won't work.
I hope someone here can help me fix it!

Thanks in advance,
Joost

Answer (score 0):

OK I managed to find a solution. Credits link included at the bottom of the script.

**Please note**: since you can remove the retention label from the top-level folder from within the SharePoint Online website, which will be propagated to all child folders (subfolders), I use this script only to remove retention labels from **files**. If you prefer this script to also remove the retention label from folders, simply remove the if-else condition.

```
#Set Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursitename"
$FolderServerRelativeURL = "/sites/yoursitename/Shared Documents/yourfoldername"
   
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL
 
#Get the Folder to download
$Folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $FolderServerRelativeURL -Includes ListItemAllFields.ParentList
#Get the Parent List
$List = $Folder.ListItemAllFields.ParentList
 
#Get all Items from the folder - with progress bar
$global:counter = 0;
$ListItemsNew = Get-PnPListItem -List $List -PageSize 500 -Fields FileLeafRef -ScriptBlock { Param($items) $global:counter += $items.Count; Write-Progress -PercentComplete `
                ($global:Counter / ($List.ItemCount) * 100) -Activity "Getting Items from List:" -Status "Processing Items $global:Counter to $($List.ItemCount)";} | Where {$_.FieldValues.FileRef -like "$($FolderServerRelativeUrl)*"} 
Write-Progress -Activity "Completed Retrieving Items from Folder $FolderServerRelativeURL" -Completed
 
#Get All Files and Folders from the Folder Recursively
$ListItemsNew | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.FileSystemObjectType -eq 'Folder'){
    # Do nothing
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Skipping folder"
    }else{
    Write-host -Foregroundcolor Green  "Processing: " $_.FieldValues.FileRef
    Write-host -Foregroundcolor Green  "ID: " $_.FieldValues.ID
    Set-PnPListItem -List Documents -Identity $_.FieldValues.ID -ClearLabel | Out-Null
    }
}

#Read more: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/02/sharepoint-online-get-list-items-from-folder-using-powershell.html#ixzz7PFXVH4rj
```